# How many Latin Squares are there with the following restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

This problem comes from a study of game design, specifically the wonderful abstract strategy game Kamisado, which I highly recommend for the mathematically minded.

The rules of the game are not so important, I am interested only in the board, which looks like this -

The board is an 8x8 Latin Square. I wonder how much choice the designer had in choosing the board. The only restrictions we want are that the board should be the same for both players, and that swapping two colours doesn't matter in terms of gameplay.

So the question is, more generally, "How many Latin squares of size $n$ exist which are isomorphic under a rotation of 180 degrees and symbol permutation?"

Specifically, for $n=8$, "How many possible Kamisado boards are there?". I know the answer must be in the literature somewhere, but am unfamiliar with the area and terminology. If there is a similar question somewhere please point me towards that instead.

Comment: Do you allow for swapping rows and columns? Do you know Polya's enumerations / Burnside lemma?

Comment: Yes, provided rotational symmetry is kept (so there would have to probably be an even number of row/column swaps).

And no, my interest in combinatorics is completely amateur - I will look into them though!

Comment: There is no fixer number of colors ? i.e. there could be 1,2,3,..,32. colors?

Comment: The number of colours must be the size of the board. Eg for an 8x8 board there must be 8 colours. I am happy to see solutions for smaller boards, however.

Comment: I understand the part about 180-degree rotation, but I don't understand the part about "symbol permutation".

Comment: Hey @GerryMyerson, I mean swapping two colours would not make a difference to the game play, so I wish to treat this as an isotopy class under symbol permutation (colours being symbols). This is just some terminology from Latin Square literature, I think.

Comment: I think you are just looking for the number of Latin squares that are symmetric under $180^{\circ}$ rotations, up to permutation of symbols.

Comment: The number of isotopy classes of Latin squares is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A040082 --- for $n=8$, there are 1676267. There are several other tabulations of Latin squares with various restrictions at that site, and you can find them by typing "Latin square" (without the quotes) into the search box at that page.

Comment: Yes, but which is this?

Comment: I don't know whether your type is one of the ones tabulated at oeis --- I reckon it's up to you to figure that out from the descriptions given with each sequence. Or, if you know the exact answers for smaller boards, that might narrow things down considerably. Or, you might find that even though your exact type isn't tabulated at oeis, the links there take you to sources that will help you solve the problem on your own. Don't be helpless! Look around! read stuff! try stuff!

Comment: I know @GerryMyerson, I'm just being lazy :P I will look around, I was hoping someone would just know the sequence, but I think I have enough information to work out some small cases now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question pertains to the number of Latin squares with a particular symmetry ($180^{\circ}$ rotational symmetry -- so the dimension $n$ must be even), up to equivalence under permutation of labels (colors).  To choose a single representative of each such equivalence class, consider only *normalized* Latin squares, which are those with first row equal to $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  You then want to fill in rows $2$ through ${n/2}$ in such a way that each row is a permutation of the values $1$ through $n$, and moreover, each entry $x_{i, j}$ is distinct from the entries above it in both its own column and its left-right mirror-image column: that is,
$$
x_{i,j}\not\in \left\{ x_{i,k}: k<j \right\} \cup \left\{ x_{n-i,k}: k<j \right\}
$$
for $2 \le i \le n/2$ and $1\le j \le n$.  The remaining rows are then forced by the rotational symmetry. For instance, for $n=4$ you need to fill in the second row below with $1,2,3,4$ as constrained here:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\{2,3\}& \{1,4\}&\{1,4\}&\{2,3\}
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
There are clearly just $4$ ways to do this.  For $n=8$, the first two rows are:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\not\in\{1,8\} & \not\in\{2,7\} & \not\in\{3,6\} & \not\in\{4,5\} 
& \not\in\{4,5\} & \not\in\{3,6\} & \not\in\{2,7\} & \not\in\{1,8\}
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
By brute force, there are $4752$ ways to fill in the first two rows.  For each of these, there are at most $4^8 2^8 = 16777216$ ways to fill in rows $3$ and $4$; so a (generous) upper bound on the number you're looking for is $7.9725330432 \times 10^{10}$.  This is quite accessible for a direct calculation.

Comment: This upper bound is tighter than the number of $8\times 4$ Latin rectangles ($88390995840$) -- that is, the number of ways to fill in the top half without the mirror-image column constraint -- but only slightly.

Comment: Thanks, both answers have given me some things to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Some Hints:

We have to fill the first player half, then we'll have the second player's half with symetry.

Now, we have a $n$ x $ (n/2)$ table. Just randomly fill the first line, you have $n!$ alternatives, right?

Now, filling the second line. What are our restrictions? No colour can have the same column number with the previous one, of course. And the other restriction comes from the symetry. We know that if a colour is in $i^{th}$ column in $j^{th}$ line, it is also in $(n-i+1)^{th}$ column in $(n-j)^{th}$ line. Then, the other restriction is no colour can have the same column number with $(n-$previous_column_number $+1$). Then, how many alternatives do we have?

Let's start with the first one, we have n-2 alternatives. Now, assume we had put the the first colour to $i^{th}$ column in the first line and $j^{th}$ column in the second line. And now assume we had put the second colour in the first line to $j^{th}$ column. Now, for the second colour we again have n-2 alternatives. But if we had put the first colour into a column different than the one with number $j$, we would have $n-4$ alternatives for the second colour. That is the tricky part of our problem.

Edit (further hint): What you have to find is that:

I have $n$ colours and $n$ spots. For each colour, $k$ spots are forbidden where $k$ depends on the line number, as at $i^{th}$ line, $k= n-2(i-1)$. For example, for first line there is no restriction, you can randomly locate the colours. For the second line, for each colour, 2 spots are forbidden. For third, 4 spots are forbidden etc.

If you can find the number of permutations for that restriction, you'll have your answer.

Comment: I understand parts of your answer but not all - convince me with a small example?

Comment: Can you tell which parts did you understand and which part you didn't? And this is not the whole answer, I worked on building a whole solution but it's still hard.

Comment: Understandable example, $4$x$4$: (it's hard to do with $6$x$6$). You randomly fill the first line, let's say $(a,b,c,d)$. Now, you know that you'll have $(d,c,b,a)$ in the forth line. If you try to fill the second line, what are your restrictions for $a$? You can't put it in the first and forth columns, because they're full. You're gonna put it into second or third column, and that will make you put $d$ into the other column than where you put $a$. Same thing will happen for $b$ and $c$. Then you have $4! \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 96$ different solutions for $4$x$4$.

Comment: Here, it's simple to calculate the alternatives for second line, because restrictions give us only $4$ alternatives. But what I meant is, the restrictions are actually clear. For $6$x$6$ for example, if your first line is like $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$, you cannot put $a$ and $f$ to first and sixth columns, $b$ and $e$ into second and fifth columns, $c$ and $d$ into third and forth columns. What you have to find is a formula for the number of alternatives with those types of restrictions where I mean $2$ restricted spots for every two elements in $n$ length chain.

Comment: For 6, it's gonna be $122$ if I did not miscalculate it. And it's only for the second line. Of course you have to calculate the number of alternatives for third line and see that most of the alternatives in second line reaches a dead end. Take the propoer ones and multiplicate with $6!$. You have to find a formula or something, but of course you have to claim a formula and show it by induction. That's why I started with $4$ and tried to find the solution for $6$.

Comment: Sorry, not $122$, $112$ of course. I reached to $112$ with putting the $a$ into some random spot, then calculating the alternatives. I saw that there are only $2$ types, leading to $4$ and $10$ solutions and there are 8 versions of them. But some of them are going to dead end in the last step, as I said. What I recommend is to write a program drawing all the alternatives by using the algorithm above. Make it for $n = 4,5,6,7,8,....$ and try to find a relation between them. Then try to show that your claim is true, using induction.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me some stuff to think about and work on!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know if you have any process. I'll try to write a program if I have some spare time.